# API compatibility between FAST Search Server and Search Server 2010 Express

Tags: search, fast-search

I'm looking to feed content into FAST Search Server . However, for development purposes, I would ideally use Search Server 2010 Express which is free to download and use.

Before going down that road, is there a common API which I can use for pushing content into both Search Server Express and FAST Search Server or do I have to use the FAST Search Server APIs? I have previously used the Java API provided by fast.no .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a push API for FAST Search Server for SharePoint, but it is discontinued (was the day it was released), and I would not recommend using it.

The primary way of indexing in FS4SP is as it is in Search Server Express, via the included connectors in the Search Service Application via Central Admin.

If I'm not mistaken you have SharePoint/Web/File Server connectors in Express, same as you have in SharePoint. Besides this, you should use BCS for feeding data from for example databases.

If you have a license for FS4SP then you can very well use SharePoint and FS4SP for development purposes on the same machine (which is what I do). No need to use Express.